# Build Name Setter Plugin Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, plugins

The below command has been working for the past 8 months but now it throws error for the build Name and Description Setter plugin.

buildName "${app_name}"

The plugin version is 2.1.0. Jenkins version is 2.281. Does the syntax needs to be changed? If yes, please help with the same or any other solutions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The plugin hasn't changed the last 10 months so are you sure your variable is not empty / null or something similar?

Comment: The Jenkins version doesn't support  this syntax. I found a work around. Now I'm using currentBuild.displayName inside the script{}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jenkins version doesn't support this syntax. The workaround is to use currentBuild.displayName inside the script{} like below.

```html
script{
currentBuild.displayName = "${APP_SHORT_NAME} - ${VERSION_NUM} - ${build_triggered_by}"
currentBuild.description = "ODP-DAAS-${APP_SHORT_NAME} in ${REPO_NAME} with ${VERSION_NUM} by ${build_triggered_by}"
}
```